# webbrowser в Python не открывает сайт

Tags: python, flask, webbrowser

Сделал небольшую API на Flask'e. Вчера все работало от и до, сегодня просто отвалилась функция открытия сайта по ключу. Ничего в коде со вчерашнего дня, вроде бы, не трогал. Из-за чего не работает - ума не приложу, уже все перепробовал.

```
@toWebsite.route('/Hash', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def toWebsite_func():
    Hash = request.form['Hash']
    webbrowser.open('https://www.google.com')
    if r.exists(Hash) == 1:
        webbrowser.open(r.get(Hash).decode('utf-8'))
        return render_template('toWebsite/toWebsite.html')
    else:
        return render_template('toWebsite/toWebsite.html', q='Вы ввели недопустимые символы. Попробуйте снова!')
```

`webbrowser.open('https://www.google.com')` конкретно это добавил для примера. Даже такая запись, вне логики с прямым указанием на сайт не работает.

Никакой ошибки нету, ничего. Оно просто игнорирует инструкцию. Сам код выполняется, через дебагер проверял.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Замените

```
webbrowser.open(...
```

на

```
    return redirect("http://www.example.com", code=302)
```